# Extra lines added to Excel chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I've got these charts that I'm trying to recreate from another file.  On the right side of the x-axis, a bunch of gray lines appear that I just cant seem to get rid of.  I think it has something to do with the blank cells my chart and the one I'm coping have for their data sets.  Only difference I can think of is that my blank cells have a formula that make it blank and the old file is empty and blank without anything in the cell.  Any help is appreciated.

Chart:

[image: Chart 1]

Data Set:

[image: Data Set]

Comment: If the lines don't appear when you don't have the formula, try formatting the cells to show nothing when their value is `0` instead of using the formula. This custom format should do the trick: `0;0;`

Comment: Could you please write that which version of Excel you are using since it's typical chart has 5 data sets for Bars & Lines in different colors,, this can be created in lower versions also but if I'm not wrong the data set you have used is no sufficient  !!

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 (MS) (16.0.13127.21624) 64-bit.

@cybernetic.nomad The cells just had a General format.  None of the cells return a 0, everything that needed to be was blank.  I tried the 0;0; cell format but didn't change anything